# Is there a way to use @Editable (Glass-mapper) and an anonymous model in an html input placeholder?

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper, placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

I have an input box and I would like to be able to have the placeholder text XP editor friendly.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@Editable(x => x.PlaceholderText)" autofocus=autofocus />
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be difficult to update placeholder text in the input field because whenever you will update placeholder text, the cursor will show in the input field.

There could be one way where you can add `Edit Frame` in between input fields like below:

```
@using (BeginEditFrame(Model.Page, "Edit PlaceholderText", x => x.PlaceholderText))
{
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  autofocus=autofocus />
}
```

Here is the link for `Glass edit frame`:
https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/09/11/glass-edit-frame-immediately-invoking-wrapper/

Comment: So there is no way for me to escape it?   It doesn't really matter that the cursor will show in the input field as long as the feeling/flow is available that one can update the placeholder text.

Comment: Not really, using edit frame you can easily update placeholder text

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.